# Using ternary operator when include layout with databinding

Tags: android

How to use ternary operator when include layout with `dataBinding`?

I'm trying to include different layouts by some `TextView`'s text length.

This is my `xml` code:

```
<include
   android:id = "@+id/toolbar_write"
   layout = "@{textTitle.length > 0 ? @layout/toolbar_write : @layout/toolbar_show}"
 />
```

But in preview nothing is included.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after running into what I assume is the same error as you:

> included value (@{data.someBoolean ? @layout/a : @layout/b}) must start with @layout/.

I suspect it's not possible because data binding generates code from the layout, including any nested layouts. For example, if foo.xml declares `<include android:id="@+id/bar" layout="@layout/bar" />` and bar.xml defines `<TextView android:id="@+id/greeting">`, the generated `FooBindingImpl` allows you to do this: `fooBinding.bar.greeting.setText("hello")`.

When you use a ternary for a text view's text, for example, the runtime value of one variable determines what value is passed to `TextView#setText()`. But the value of `layout` on an `<include>` affects what code should be generated.